# Send message to Telegram with python request

Tags: python, flask, heroku, request, telegram

I tried to send message to telegram with python.
I using python on heroku. And `import request` library.

The Message has been sent successfully, but have an issue with Heroku:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490239+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490239+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490240+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490240+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.finalize_request(rv)
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490241+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490241+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.make_response(rv)
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490241+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2097, in make_response
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490242+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise TypeError(
2023-01-15T06:01:21.490242+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

This is my code:

```py
def Send_Message_Telegram(data):
    send_text = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + str(config.tgtoken) +\
    '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + str(config.channel) + '&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&text=' + data

    try:
        print("try")
        response = requests.request("post", send_text)#.status_code
        print("response: {}".format(response))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This is the correct syntax
        raise SystemExit(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a return statement at the end of the try loop like this:

```
def Send_Message_Telegram(data):
    send_text = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + str(config.tgtoken) +
    '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + str(config.channel) + '&parse_mode=MarkdownV2&text=' + data
    try:
        print("try")
        response = requests.request("post", send_text)
        print("response: {}".format(response))
        return 0
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  
        raise SystemExit(e)
```